# Как работают функции fputcsv, fgetcsv?

Tags: php

Обе функции fputcsv и fgetcsv работают со строками. Читают/пишут по одной строке, т.е., чтобы считать/записать в csv массив данных, делать это нужно в цикле

```
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

Как работают данные функции?

Если в массиве 10 тысяч строк, то это будет 10 тысяч обращений к файловой системе? Если что-то в этом духе, то не рациональнее ли сформировать строку и одним разом ее записать в файл?

Comment: имхо, как бы там ни было, но 10к строк не будет равно 10к файловых операций из-за буферизации

Comment: будет - ядро не будет кешировать операции с файловыми дескрипторами.

Comment: @Aios что тогда делают fflush() и stream_set_write_buffer() к примеру? по-моему как раз надо заморочиться, чтобы никакого кэширования не случилось по дороге...

Answer (score 1):

Да, эти функции читают-пишут по одной строке. И это замечательно. Они и должны работать только так и никак иначе.

По поводу же страхов, вызванных воображаемой нерациональностью такого подхода, позволю себе процитировать высказывание великого программиста Н.Вирта:

> Исправление воображаемых проблем с производительностью - корень всех зол.

Что означает: проблемы с производительностью надо исправлять только тогда, когда они есть. То есть, в данном случае надо сначала получить хоть какую-то проблему с производительностью при записи 10000 строк, и только потом пугаться и пытаться что-то исправить.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210944/fputcsv-running-out-of-memory-during-creation-of-larger-files

А вообще смотрите в сторону perl и python. У них с обработкой строк и потоками - по проще будет.

Comment: Есть такая поговорка, "Слышит звон, да не знает где он". Кроме умения по-быстрому нагуглить ссылку, нужно еще и умение понять, что по ней написано.